# How can I prevent line numbers from appearing in .bash_history?

Tags: bash, history

Recently, line numbers have started to appear in my `.bash_history` file. Where before, for example I might have had just

```
rm -rf *
```

I now have entries like

```
#1565909296
rm -rf *
```

How do I prevent those line limbers (or timestamps, or whatever they are) from accumulating in my `.bash_history` file?

---

These numbers seem to have nothing to do with any of my settings (and in any case started to appear without any adjustments to theses settings having been made):

```
$ grep -i 'hist' .bash* .profile
.bash_profile:export HISTCONTROL=ignorespace:ignoredups
.bash_profile:#export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
.bash_profile:#export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:ignorespace:ignoredups
.bash_profile:export HISTSIZE=10000
.bash_profile:export HISTFILESIZE=500000
.bash_profile:SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=0
.bash_profile:export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%y-%m-%d-%T   '
```

Comment: see:https://www.shellhacks.com/tune-command-line-history-bash/

Comment: @historystamp Relevance?

Comment: Get rid of timestamps.

Comment: @historystamp Sorry, what does this have to do with the question?

Comment: "(or timestamps, or whatever they are)" was in the question.

Comment: Could you post a few lines of the file ".bash_history", so we can see what you are seeing?

Comment: @historystamp It’s right there in the question: a number like that before every logged history entry.

Comment: Can you add the results of the following command to your question? -`grep -i 'hist'  .bash* .profile`- This could identify which startup file is the culprit.

Comment: @fd0: Added. Though as the OP states, I don't think any of that is relevant.

Comment: You need to remove the `export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%y-%m-%d-%T   '` from your `.bash_profile` file to stop the _timestamp_ from being added to the `~/.bash_history` file, as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @fd0, placing `export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%y-%m-%d-%T '` in my `.bash_profile` file produces epoch timestamps in my `.bash_history` file and removing it stops the epoch timestamps in my `.bash_history` file. The _strftime_ notation is use when using the `history` _command_ but an epoch timestamp is used in the `.bash_history` file when `HISTTIMEFORMAT` is set.

Answer (score 1):

Update: The recent edit you've made to you question shows the following line being in your `.bash_profile` file:

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%y-%m-%d-%T   '
```

Remove this line to stop the *timestamp* from being added to the `~/.bash_history` file.

---

Original Answer:

As `HISTTIMEFORMAT` is not set by default, up to an including macOS Mojave, you'll need to check one of the following files to see where it was added:

- `/etc/bashrc`
- `/etc/profile`
- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.bash_login`
- `~/.profile`
- `~/.bashrc`

Removing the line that has `HISTTIMEFORMAT` from the file that has it will stop the *timestamp* from being added to the `~/.bash_history` file.

Note: The *dot* files mentioned in the `$HOME` *directory* are hidden and some may not exist.